# Fb.ui only shows up after second click

Tags: javascript, facebook, events, dom-events

I am creating a Facebook application which should allow the user do post something on his/her wall.

The main actions take place within a Flash movie. When the user is finished the Flash movie uses `ExternalConnection` to notify the JavaScript. The JavaScript now display a link, that has been hidden all the time and attach a `onClick` event to this link.

The `onClick` event looks like this:

```
Fb.ui({
    method: 'stream.publish',
    message: 'foobar',
},function(response) {
    me.getById("publishcontainer").style.display="none";
});
```

My problem now is. When I click this link Facebook show the loading window, but nothing happens. If I click the link a second time, Facebook shows the publishing dialog as expected.

Anybody any idea how this problem could be solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bug of the current Facebook JavaScript API: http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=10180

Comment: Link expired instead you should provide a solution